# C# read customHeaders value from web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have requirement where I need to read customHeaders value in WCF. Below is sample config file of my application. I need to find programmatically value of "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" key. Please help in achieving the same.

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:4200"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Request-Method" value="POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-Requested-With,Content-Type"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

I tried below but it is not working.

```
Configuration config = serverManager.GetWebConfiguration("Web.Config");
ConfigurationSection httpProtocolSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/httpProtocol");
ConfigurationElementCollection customHeadersCollection = httpProtocolSection.GetCollection("customHeaders");
foreach(var element in customHeadersCollection)
{
    Response.Write(element.Attributes[0].Name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this example from Microsoft to read these values.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpprotocol/customheaders/#sample-code

You need a reference to `Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll` to access these classes.

```
      using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
      {
         Configuration config = serverManager.GetWebConfiguration("Default Web Site");
         ConfigurationSection httpProtocolSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/httpProtocol");
         ConfigurationElementCollection customHeadersCollection = httpProtocolSection.GetCollection("customHeaders");

         // what you want is in customerHeadersCollection
      }
```